# Does Enumerable.Cast<T> Copy Objects?

Tags: c#, casting

I have an object hierarchy

```
public class MyBase {}
public class MyDerived : MyBase {}
```

and have

```
List<MyBase> myList;
```

that is actually filled with instances of `MyDerived`

In order to access that list as a `List<MyDerived>`, I'm doing the following:

```
myList.Cast<MyDerived>().ToList()
```

I read the MSDN docs on [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but it's not clear to me whether the `Cast<T>` and `ToList` operations make a new *copy* of the objects in memory, or simply allow the compiler to *access* the existing objects as if they were a `List<MyDerived>`.

Comment: It is actually _impossible_ to copy an arbitrary managed object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As its name implies, `Cast<T>()` just casts objects:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) { 
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource; 
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj; 
}
```

In .Net, it is fundamentally impossible to copy an arbitrary object.  It would make no sense for `Cast<T>()` to copy things.

Note that if `T` is a value type, `Cast<T>()` *will* copy the structs; value types are *always* copied. (except when passed as `ref` parameters)

Comment: Using ToList() does creates a copy, or doesn't?

Comment: @sos00: Wrong.  It is impossible to copy an object.  `ToList()` makes a copy of the _list_, but it still refers to the same objects.

Comment: It might be useful to mention the converse of your own comment here: If one were to implement this code exactly like this _inside_ the assembly containing the type operated on, the behaviour may be different from what the standard extension does: `(TResult)obj` may invoke a user-defined conversion operator (e.g. `class X { public static implicit operator Y() { ... }`)

Comment: @sehe: Still wrong.  Generics are done at runtime; a cast to or from a generic type will _never_ invoke a user-defined operator.

Comment: Sigh. Where can I find this information? By the way, this also implies that a cast to a non-generic type may still invoke a userdefined conversion? E.g. `List<X> xs; var convertedtoYs = xs.Cast<Y>();` ? You see, there is _nothing generic_ about X nor Y

Comment: The point that confused me was the MSDN documentation on casting in C# that describes casting an int to a double (value types) which stated that the int is copied.  Makes sense that arbitrary objects are not copied.

Comment: @sehe: You're right; I meant to say generic type _parameter_.  You can create user-defined conversions between _concrete_ generic types, and cast using them just like concrete non-generic types.  However, user-defined conversions cannot be generic or involve generic type parameters.

Comment: @EricJ.: Yes.  Casting refers to three very different things: Built-in language conversions (eg, `int` to `double`), user-defined conversions, and runtime type-casts.  Only the third is _selected_ at runtime.  Eric Lippert does a good job explaining these things; I don't have links offhand.

Comment: @sehe: `Where can I find this information?` That's a good question.  I amalgamated this knowledge from years of personal experience and from reading Eric Lippert.  It is most important to _understand_ how it works, by logically extrapolating from specifications and behavior.  Programming is all about intense logical thought.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx for a good description.

Comment: @SLaks: great. Rephrasing the way I finally understood it: 'convertibility' is not available as a generic _argument type_ constraint, therefore `void F<TX,TY>(TX x) { return (TY) x; }` will never compile. It took me a while because I do too much C++ lately :)

Comment: @SLaks that link, while good reading, purposely avoids the issue of generics.

Comment: @sehe: Yes.  This is one of the primary differences between generics and templates.  I, coming from the opposite side, am just barely aware of the neat tricks you can do with templates.

Answer (score 0):

No

Unsurprisingly (!) it `Casts` them.

> I read the MSDN docs on Enumerable.Cast, but it's not clear to me whether the Cast and ToList operations make a new copy of the objects in memory, or simply allow the compiler to access the existing objects as if they were a List.

Yes, specifically this scenario will allow the compiler to access the existing objects as if they were a `List<MyDerived>`

Comment: User-defined conversions are purely a compile-time feature; no runtime method ever uses them.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks again. I learned something today. And you saved me the effort of trying it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The cast call:

```
enumerable.Cast<T>();
```

is equivalent to:

```
enumerable.Select(x=>(T)x)
```

And:

```
enumerable.ToList<T>()
```

is equivalent to:

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>();
foreach(T item in enumerable)
{
   myList.Add(item);
}
```

so...

```
enumerable.Cast<T2>.ToList()
```

is equivalent to:

```
List<T2> myList = new List<T2>();
foreach(T item in enumerable)
{
   myList.Add((T2)item);
}
```

Both of which will promptly blow up if enumerable contains any entries that are not of a type castable to T2.

It would be safer as

```
  enumerable.Where(x=>x is T2).Cast<T2>().ToList();
```

or

```
  enumerable.OfType<T2>().ToList();
```

However, none of these copies the objects contained in the original collection.  They just create collections containing references to the original objects.

Comment: So memory _is_ allocated for a new List<T>?

Comment: Yes.  Memory is allocated for the list data structure.

Comment: Note:  I added another alternative utilising the OfType extension method that filters and casts to the defined type. (enumerable.OfType<T2>().ToList()) will return a list of only those elements castable to the T2 type.