# ReferenceEquals with casting challenge. Casting to child type make ReferenceEquals return false

Tags: c#, reference, equality

Casting does not make copies of objects. More concretely [IEnumerable.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-6.0), according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198876/does-enumerable-castt-copy-objects) resource, which makes total sense. However for this app, find [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAx2oW), reference equals is false if I change the log at the end from the `Cast<BaseClass>` to `Cast<DerivedClass1>`. Check logs at the main program.

`are equal:  True areEqualRef: True areEqualRef: False`

Posting the code, just in case, omit it of you get my point playing around with the fiddle :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    public class BaseClass {
        string name = "I am base";
        public Type type;
        public enum Type { 
            a,b,c,d
        }
        public BaseClass(Type type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
    {
        string name = "I am derivedA";

        public DerivedClass1(): base(Type.a) {
        
        }
    }


    public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
    {
        string name = "I am derivedB";
        public DerivedClass2() : base(Type.b)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Dictionary<BaseClass.Type, List<BaseClass>> dict = new Dictionary<BaseClass.Type, List<BaseClass>>();

        public Foo() {

            dict[BaseClass.Type.a] = new List<BaseClass>();
            dict[BaseClass.Type.b] = new List<BaseClass>();
            dict[BaseClass.Type.c] = new List<BaseClass>();
            dict[BaseClass.Type.d] = new List<BaseClass>();

            AddItem(new DerivedClass1());
            AddItem(new DerivedClass1());

            AddItem(new DerivedClass2());
            AddItem(new DerivedClass2());
            AddItem(new DerivedClass2());
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetEnumByType<T>(BaseClass.Type type) where T : BaseClass
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                if (type == BaseClass.Type.a)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"are equal:  { object.ReferenceEquals(dict[type].Cast<T>(), dict[BaseClass.Type.a])}");
                }

                return dict[type].Cast<T>();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddItem<T>(T item) where T : BaseClass
        {
            dict[item.type].Add(item);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            IEnumerable myList = foo.GetEnumByType<BaseClass>(BaseClass.Type.a);

            Console.WriteLine($"areEqualRef: {object.ReferenceEquals(foo.dict[BaseClass.Type.a].Cast<BaseClass>(), foo.dict[BaseClass.Type.a])}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Updated the fiddle with both logs to avoid the need of copy/pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to notionally separate what is being compared here. When it says that `Enumerable.Cast<T>` doesn't make copies of objects, it is talking about the individual objects *in the sequence*. Not the sequence itself. In order to perform the necessary reshaping, the sequence returned from the `Cast<T>` method is a different wrapper/decorator instance over the original sequence.

Since you're using `ReferenceEquals` *on the sequence*, this will report `false`. However, if you were to compare each object *from the sequences* (pairwise in turn), you would find that *those* were the same objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was not aware of that. And is there a builtin way to check if a collection is passed around by many classes in a big app, if actually none of their elements inside has changed reference? (meaning without self implementation looping through the two sequence refs comparing all the elements)

Comment: I mean to find out if both collections point to the same sequence object

Comment: @rustyBucketBay the SequenceEqual method comes close, but you'd need to supply a custom comparer that uses referenceequals